# Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in function entity_extract_ids(). How to solve?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I use Drupal 7. I added new type of node, this type has some fields, which I output on the page.tpl.php.
I use this constructions:

```
<?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_description', 'field_items'));?>
```

And:

```
<?php print $title;?>
```

What I am doing wrong?

And how I can output some fields from node without errors?
Thank you.
P.S. Sorry for bad English, I use Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated on the [help page for the field_view_field function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7), it shouldn't be used within templates. Use render($content[FIELD_NAME]) instead.